# Why am I getting unbalanced quotes in my macro?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I've got a macro which includes some comments, since I'm good about documenting my code.  For some reason, when I run this macro, I get a hanging quote.  Why?

Test macro that replicates this:

```
%macro testme;
* Comment that is in my macro that doesn't work;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
run;

%mend testme;

%testme;
```

On the first execution it fails entirely, and on the second it gives me the message `ERROR: No matching %MACRO statement for this %MEND statement.`

Comment: You may want to include the exact error message for search-engine friendliness: `ERROR: No matching %MACRO statement for this %MEND statement.`

Comment: Actually- no. You get no error message: you get nothing (as it hasn't reached the end of the string!).

Comment: Ah yes, but on a second submit (which is likely to happen in an interactive session) you get that message.

Answer (score 5):

In the SAS Macro language, single line comments aren't treated quite the same as in the base SAS language.  Specifically:

```
*something;
```

Is not a comment in the SAS macro language!  It will be submitted to regular SAS, and will become a comment... but it won't be ignored by the SAS Macro parser, which is where this is a problem.  It tokenizes it, which causes it to not ignore the quotation character.

You need to use "PL/1" style comments (ie, block comments) to make this work properly; or just don't use apostrophes (ie, `do not` instead of `don't` in comments).

```
%macro testme;
/* Comment won't break things now!*/
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
run;

%mend testme;

%testme;
```

See [the SAS support article on Using Comments In Macros](http://support.sas.com/kb/32/684.html) for more information.